# InvalidInputException error for Availability Zone while creating a connection using boto3 to AWS Glue

Tags: boto3, aws-glue

I am trying to establish a connection to an RDS instance using Connections in AWS Glue. I am trying to do this using boto3 client and the `create_connection()` method.

This is what I have so far

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    glue= boto3.client('glue')
    response= glue.create_connection(
        ConnectionInput={
            'Name': 'TEST_CONNECTION',
            'ConnectionType': 'JDBC',
            'MatchCriteria':[
                'string',
            ],
            'ConnectionProperties':{
                'JDBC_CONNECTION_URL': 'jdbc:mysql://xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:xxxx/xxxx',
                'username':'xxxxx',
                'password':'xxxxxx'
            },
            'PhysicalConnectionRequirements':{
                'SubnetId':'subnet-xxxxxxxx',
                'SecurityGroupIdList':[
                    'sg-xxxxxxxx',
                ],
                'AvailabilityZone':'us-east-1a'
            }
        }
    )
```

This is the **error** I am receiving

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateConnection operation: Validation for connection properties failed",
  "errorType": "InvalidInputException",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      23,
      "lambda_handler",
      "'AvailabilityZone':'us-east-1a'"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      316,
      "_api_call",
      "return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      626,
      "_make_api_call",
      "raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have tried with other AZ but to no avail. 
Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Glue, but the error message is saying that there is a problem with the connection properties. Some web search found a similar call on [aws-big-data-blog/export_rs_logs_solution_deployment_template.json at master · amazon-archives/aws-big-data-blog](https://github.com/amazon-archives/aws-big-data-blog/blob/master/aws-blog-retain-redshift-stl/cfn/export_rs_logs_solution_deployment_template.json). Just a thought... Try `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` in uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

Making the USERNAME and PASSWORD in uppercase works.

```
import json
import boto3    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    glue= boto3.client('glue')
    response= glue.create_connection(
        ConnectionInput={
            'Name': 'TEST_CONNECTION',
            'ConnectionType': 'JDBC',
            'ConnectionProperties':{
                'JDBC_CONNECTION_URL': 'jdbc:mysql://xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:xxxx/xxxx',
                'USERNAME':'xxxxx',
                'PASSWORD':'xxxxxx'
            },
            'PhysicalConnectionRequirements':{
                'SubnetId':'subnet-xxxxxxx',
                'SecurityGroupIdList':[
                    'sg-xxxxxx'
                ],
                'AvailabilityZone':'us-east-1a'
            }
        }
    )
```